# Determine the function for the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to determine the function for the linear transformation $T:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$
which satisfies:
$$
T(u_1)=u_2, T(u_2)=u_1, T(u_3)=u_3,
$$
where
$$u_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2\\
-2
\end{pmatrix},$$
$$u_2=\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix},$$
and
$$u_3=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{2}{11}\\
-\frac{10}{11}\\
1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

> I'm not totally sure how to find this. Can anyone help me?

I think maybe that I can consider the base $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ and the  same standard base $E=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ for $R^3$. For any vector $x \in R^4$, we can then find $[T(x)]_B$ and $[x]_B$. I think it is true that that $x=[x]_E=P_{E \leftarrow B}[x]_B$, and maybe I can use this, but I'm not sure how. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Determine the function", meaning find the matrix for $T$?

Comment: Yeah I think it will ended up being a matrix

Answer (score 1):

There's a theorem that says if $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear transformation, then $T(x)=Ax$ for the matrix $A=[T(e_1)\,\, T(e_2)\,\, \cdots \,\, T(e_n)],$ where $e_1,\dots e_n$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n.$ So you can express the $u_i$ in terms of the standard basis, use the linearity of $T$ to find $T(e_i)$, and then form the matrix given in this theorem.

Comment: I think I follow the argument, but which  equation systems do I have to solve to find $(_1)$, $(_2)$ and $(_3)$?

Comment: Here, $u_2=5e_1-e_2$, so by the linearity of $T$, what does $T(u_2)=T(5e_1-e_2)$ look like?

Comment: So $T(u_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
-1 \\
0 \\

\end{pmatrix}$, or am I wrong? and how can I then find $T(e_1)$ for example?

Comment: What does linearity of $T$ mean?

Comment: So I get that $T(u_2)=5T(E_1)-T(e_2)$? But how can I use this?

Comment: Yes. This gives you an equation: $5T(e_1)-T(e_2)=u_1$ (might as well just leave the $u_1$ on the RHS for now). Do this with all $3$ conditions and you will have $3$ equations, with the $3$ unknowns being $T(e_1),T(e_2),T(e_3)$. Yes these are vectors, but we can still treat it as a system of equations as usual, just now the unknowns happen to be vectors. No problem.

Comment: Aha, now I see!! That makes sense. That will I try. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Forsure. Good luck :)